# Laravel : Form not submitting but everything looks right?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, submit

I have a very strange problem with Laravel . I'm sure I miss something but not sure what.
When submit there's no record in DB. But it's very strange that not submit even without validator. Here is the code.

The model:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Registration extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */

protected $table = 'register';

protected $fillable =         array('first_name','middle_name','last_name','address','phone','email','age','growth','weight','shoe_size','cloth_size','languages','eye_color');

}
```

The Controller :

```
<?php 

class RegistrationController extends BaseController {


public function getAgency() {

    return View::make('agency');
}


public function postAgency(){
    $rules = array(
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'middle_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' =>'required',
        'address' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'age' => 'required',
        'growth' =>'required',
        'weight' => 'required',
        'shoe_size' => 'required',
        'cloth_size' => 'required',
        'languages' => 'required',
        'eye_color' => 'required'
        );

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),$rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {


        return Redirect::to('/agency')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();

    }
    else {
        $registration = new Registration;
        $registration->first_name = Input::get('first_name');
        $registration->middle_name = Input::get('middle_name');
        $registration->last_name = Input::get('last_name');
        $registration->address  = Input::get('address');
        $registration->phone = Input::get('phone');
        $registration->email  = Input::get('email');
        $registration->age = Input::get('age');
        $registration->growth = Input::get('growth');
        $registration->weight = Input::get('weight');
        $registration->shoe_size = Input::get('shoe_size');
        $registration->cloth_size = Input::get('cloth_size');
        $registration->languages = Input::get('languages');
        $registration->eye_color = Input::get('eye_color'); 

        $registration->save();

        return Redirect::to('/agency')->with('global',"Thank You!");
        }
    }
}
```

The View (agency.blade.php):

```
@extends('layouts.main')


@section('content')
<div class="container">

 <div class="stepwizard">
    <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
    <div class="stepwizard-step">
            <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</a>
        <p><img src="images/leftShoe.png" alt="" class="shoes"></p>
    </div>
        <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">2</a>
        <p><img src="images/rightShoe.png" alt="" class="shoes"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="#step-3" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">3</a>
        <p><img src="images/duoShoes.png" alt="" class="shoes"></p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<form method="POST" action="{{URL::action('agency-post')}}">
<div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
<div class="col-md-12">

<button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="form-group">
<label>First Name</label>
<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
@if ($errors->has('first_name')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('first_name') }}</p> @endif
        </div>
<div class="form-group">
<label >Middle Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="middle_name" placeholder="Middle Name">
@if ($errors->has('middle_name')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('middle_name') }}</p> @endif
        </div>
<div class="form-group">
            <label >Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
              @if ($errors->has('last_name')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('last_name') }}</p> @endif
        </div>

<div class="form-group">
            <label >Address</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Address">
              @if ($errors->has('address')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('address') }}</p> @endif
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label >Phone</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
              @if ($errors->has('phone')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('phone') }}</p> @endif
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label >Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="super@cool.com">
             @if ($errors->has('email')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</p> @endif
        </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label >Age</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" name="age" placeholder="Age">
             @if ($errors->has('age')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('age') }}</p> @endif
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label >Growth</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" name="growth" placeholder="Growth">
             @if ($errors->has('growth')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('growth') }}</p> @endif
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label >Weight</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" name="weight" placeholder="Weight">
             @if ($errors->has('weight')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('weight') }}</p> @endif
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label >Shoe size</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" name="shoe_size" placeholder="Shoe size">
             @if ($errors->has('shoe_size')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('shoe_size') }}</p> @endif
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label >Size Clothing</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" name="cloth_size" placeholder="Cloth Size">
             @if ($errors->has('cloth_size')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('cloth_size') }}</p> @endif
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label >Spoken Languages</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" name="languages" placeholder="Spoken Languages">
             @if ($errors->has('languages')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('languages') }}</p> @endif
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label >Eye Color</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" name="eye_color" placeholder="Eye Color">
             @if ($errors->has('eye_color')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('eye_color') }}</p> @endif
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">

            <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="row setup-content" id="step-3">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3> Additional Information</h3>
            <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label">Skills</label>
                  <textarea maxlength="500"  class="form-control"  rows="5" placeholder="Enter your skills"></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label">Additional Information</label>
                  <textarea maxlength="500" type="text" class="form-control"  rows="5" placeholder="Enter additional information for you"></textarea>
              </div>
        {{Form::token()}}
        {{Form::submit('Finish!')}}

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Route.php

```
Route::get('/agency',array(
'as' => 'agency',
'uses' => 'RegistrationController@getAgency'
));

Route::post('/agency',array(
'as' => 'agency-post',
'uses' => 'RegistrationController@postAgency'
));
```

It's more strange that when write in loop $validator->fails() { return 'fails';}

page only reload nothing happens.

Comment: First of all check if your validation fails or if the code goes further. Just ```dd()``` inside your ```if($validation->fails())```.

Comment: you have to debug and find some error code, I use this [clockwork](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork) It can see current request(get/post) & executed sql queries